# Custom Post type slider

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, slider, custom-post-type

I've looked and looked, but I can't find a Wordpress plugin that gives me ALL the following functionality available in a Slider:

- Display custom posts from a custom post type I have developed myself - - displays Featured image, title and excerpt (not full post)
- Display in random order – from a list of 100’s of custom posts of that type
- Responsive so adapts to screen/container size

Images and excerpts are of varying sizes.

As a bonus I’d like to display some custom taxonomy names associated with the posts as well, though that’s not as important.

I've found ones that do everything except display in random order as an option, or they are not responsive, or they don's support custom post types, or they expect you to create  a new custom post type of a particular type specified by the plugin.

I don't mind paying for the right one if it's out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a great slider by woothemes called [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) personally I use it on all my sites and you can use it without a plugin.
Download the slider from that link i provided.

copy the `flexslider.css` file and `jquery.flexslider-min.js` file into your theme folder.

in your **header.php**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<YOUR_THEME_LINK>/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<YOUR_THEME_LINK>/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider .flexslider').flexslider({
               animation: 'slide',
                slideshowSpeed: 9000,
                animationSpeed: 900,
                pauseOnAction: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav: true, 
                controlsContainer: ".flexslider",
        });
    });
})(jQuery)</script>
```

in your **homepage** file (or anywhere you want the slider to show)

```
<section id="slider">
      <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => '<YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE>','orderby' => 'rand')); if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <li class="slide">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </li>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks you SO MUCH Mark - it worked a dream. I was able to style it myself to look like the other parts of the site and was able to add all the custom taxonomy information I needed. The only thing  I had to do extra from your instructions was copy the fonts directory and update the .css file to find it for the navigation arrows.